# Using ModelBuilder or Python parser of Field Calculator to check values between two datasets?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, modelbuilder, field-calculator, iterator

I have a *.dbf that I need to check values against for a shapefile.

I need to report whether the values match the dbf in the shapefile and, if not, what the value should have been (in two new fields)

Here's what I have:

- DBF (correct values for all unique combinations of two fields reported in a third field), sort of like a look up table.
  For each unique value within field A and B, there is a value in field C.
- A shapefile to check the value in field C against the dbf based off fields A & B within that shapefile.

I know a very inefficient work-around (concatenating fields then manually joining them), but I'm trying to get more familiar with ModelBuilder and Python.

I prefer using ModelBuilder so if this can be done in ModelBuilder with maybe just a Python field calculate (simple if then statement) that would be ideal.

I have very little Python knowledge and limited ModelBuilder knowledge (basically I know how to drag and drop geoprocessing tools and set up parameters, but I struggle with the iterators and loops).

Comment: Honestly it sounds like your "inefficient workaround" is actually the most direct way to approach the problem. You could drag all the steps you were doing manually into a model (e.g. Add Field, Concatenate SHP_A and SHP_B, Join to DBF, Select Layer by Attribute where SHP_C <> DBF_C , and Calculate Field those selected records to "Not_Equivalent"). No iterators or loops or Python is needed I suspect.

Comment: On a question such as this you are most likely to attract potential answerers if you describe in detail your "inefficient workaround" and then show what you have tried in the way of improving it via ModelBuilder automation.